# Complex derivative of root function

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

Using $z=a+ib=re^{i\phi}$ and 
$$\sqrt z := \sqrt{r} e^{i\phi/2},$$

one can express both real and imaginary part of $\sqrt{z}$ as
$$\Re\sqrt{z}=\sqrt{r}\cos\frac{\phi}{2}$$
$$\Im\sqrt{z}=\sqrt{r}\sin\frac{\phi}{2}$$

without using any inverse trigonometric functions.

Is such a simple decomposition also possible for $f(z)=\frac{d}{dz}\sqrt{z}$? If not, might it be possible expressed in $(a,b)$ instead of $(r,\phi)$?

**Edit:** The reason is, to avoid case-distinctions in my ongoing calculus, I want to perform with this derivative.

Comment: How are you choosing $\theta$? (It matters.)

Comment: I would like to choose $\phi\in[0,2\pi)$.

Comment: You know that if $F$ is a branch of the square root, then you have $$F'(z) = \frac{1}{2\cdot F(z)},$$ do you?

Comment: @DanielFischer I did not know this rule also applies in the complex case. Then in could be simply decomposed using complex expansion in the denominator, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We first prove what Daniel said in his comment:

**Claim:** If $F$ is a branch of the square root, then $$F^\prime(z)=\frac{1}{2\cdot F(z)}.$$

*Proof:* A holomorphic function $F:U\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ on some domain $U\subset\mathbb{C}$ is a branch of the square root if $F(z)^2=z$ for all $z\in U$. Deriving this equation using the chain rule gives $2F(z)F^\prime(z)=1$. $\square$

Then we get that your $f$ can be written as

$$f(z)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{r}} e^{-i\phi/2}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{r}}\cos(\phi/2)-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{r}}\sin(\phi/2)i$$

Comment: Why aren't we allowed to differentiate $\sqrt{z}$ in the normal way and get $-\frac{1}{\sqrt{z}}$. This is of course wrong but why? For the principle branch of $\text{Log}(z)$ we should get $e^{\text{Log}(z)}\frac{d\text{Log}(z)}{dz}=1$ i.e. the usual result $\frac{1}{z}$.